# Delays when playing sounds HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an array of sounds.
First two sounds start to play when the game is loaded. They play simultaneously and repeat. The third sound plays each time then a game event happens (ball is bumped) and here is a delay. If I don't play two first sounds, then this delay disappears. It works ok in IE but not in Chrome... Is that a Chrome bug?

```
function getSoundInstance(src) {
    var audioElement = new Audio();
    audioElement.src=src;    
    return audioElement;    
}

sounds['ocean'] = getSoundInstance('./src/audio/ocean.mp3');
sounds['music'] = getSoundInstance('./src/audio/song1.mp3');
sounds['bump'] =  getSoundInstance('./src/audio/bump.mp3');

sounds['ocean'].loop=true;
sounds['ocean'].volume=.9;
sounds['music'].loop=true;
sounds['music'].volume=.4;

sounds['ocean'].play();               
sounds['music'].play();

//when I start to play sounds['bump'] I get a delay.
```

Comment: I does sound like a bug in Chrome, but it is hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.  Can you show the rest of your script where the bump event occurs?

Comment: `sounds['bump'].play();
 this.bumpedFrom=null;
 this.touches++;
 if(this.touches >= BALL_MAXTOUCHES) {
     this.state=BALL_STATE_MAXTOUCHES;
     this.vY=this.vY/2;                     
     this.ball.cache(0, 0, 2*this.rad, 2*this.rad);                       
  }` nothing wrong with it, it works fine